# Explanation behind the observed chloroplasts in Elodea during Hypotonic vs Isotonic Solution

Tags: cell-biology, botany, plant-physiology, osmosis, chloroplasts

Me and my colleagues put the elodea leaf in distilled (hypotonic) and tap water (isotonic). We observed under the microscope that the elodea under the hypotonic solution became elongated and turgid, while the ones on isotonic solution was less firm in shape.

My confusion comes in the observed green like particles which I assume to be chloroplasts. They are scattered all over the place for hypotonic solution, while in the isotonic was located on the cell's plasma membrane.

Shouldn't the chloroplasts be on the side for a hypotonic solution due to the expansion of the vacuole? Similarly, shouldn't the chloroplasts be more scattered in the isotonic solution due to the vacuole not expanding that much?